# Toy Definition of a Topological Space

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory, boolean-algebra

Preamble:

This is a question meant to be fun and amusing -- not part of any class/homework/test/etc.  Also, please forgive my horrific typesetting.  This is my first question on this website.  I'm fluent in Latex, which seems to be close, but not exactly the language structure of this question format.

Motivation:

I was rereading about Point-Set Topology, and was considering to myself the possibility creating an alternative definition to a Topological Space.  To Recall,

> **Definition**: A Topology on a set $X$ is a collection $\tau$ of subsets of $X$ having the following properties:
>
> 1. $\emptyset$ and $X$ are in $\tau$.
> 2. The union of the elements of any subcollection of $\tau$ is in $\tau$.
> 3. The intersection of the elements of any finite subcollection of $\tau$ is in $\tau$.
>
> A set $X$ for which a topology $\tau$ has been specified is called a topological space.    That is, the ordered pair $(\tau,X)$.

-- Topology, Second Edition. James R. Munkres. Page 76.

We see here that $\tau$ is a collection of subsets, as that is what our definition states.  However, suppose instead we imagine replacing $\tau$ with the function $\rho$ which accepts two inputs and provides a boolean output.  To define explicitly:

$\rho: \{\text{ruleset}\} \times \mathscr{P}(X) \rightarrow \{1,0\}$

$\rho(\{\text{ruleset}\},U) = 1$, if $U$ is open **or** a complement of an open set according to the ruleset.

*notice here that both $X$ and $\emptyset$ would return a value of $1$, as they are both open, and complements of each other.

$\rho(\{\text{ruleset}\},U) = 0$, else.

(We define $\mathscr{P}(X)$ to be the powerset of the set $X$).

Now if the ruleset is something simple such as "If $U$ is in $\mathscr{P}(X)$" then we trivially get back the definition via $\tau$.

If the ruleset includes a proviso for an open subset $A \subseteq X$ so that the intersection of $A$ and $U$ is open provided $U$ is open in $X$, then we get the subspace topology.

Question:  Under this pretense, could we redefine a topological space from $(X,\tau) \rightarrow (X,\rho)$?  I would really would love to see this fail under some special example. >:). Many thanks in advance and happy summer 2021!

Comment: I don't see how you get back "the definition via $\tau$" (of what?) for the ruleset "if $U$ is in $\mathcal P(X)$". Can you elaborate a bit?

Comment: Ah, I hope I have not forgotten what is meant by a powerset.  If I am wrong, then please correct me:

The empty set and X are both in P(X) satisfying property (1).  Every subset (including the union/intersection of sub collections) are in P(X) satisfying (2) and (3).

I may be assuming too much regarding what is contained in a powerset.  However, if that is the case we can replace P(X) from above to be the set: {the set of subsets of X containing the arbitrary unions and finite intersections}.

Comment: If I understand you right, it can't work in general because a topology is *not* usually closed under complements. The complement of an open set is called closed.

Comment: A "ruleset" is not a well-defined object. Be precise in what you mean. The powerset $\mathscr{P}(X)$ of $X$ is the set of *all* subsets of $X$ that exist in that model of set theory.

Comment: Are you confusing the powerset $\mathcal P(X)$, which contains *all* subsets of $X$, with the actual topology $\tau$?

Comment: So $\tau \subseteq \mathscr{P}(X)$ by definition.

Comment: Your argument seems circular. The definition of $\rho$ requires that we know what an open set is ahead of time. How do you do that without a topology?

Comment: I wanted to imagine replacing a topology with an algorithm.  Choosing a ruleset would generate a particular topology.

Comment: If P(X) is swapped with the topology tau, then I feel that the game is over, since the new definition is thereby dependent on the original one.  However, if that is the case then I accept my defeat.

Comment: Bravo Calvin Khor!  I believe you found the itch I was desperately trying to scratch.  However, can we make that into a tangible example to post as the solution to this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Picking on sets that open *or* the complement of a open set is not going translate nicely into a definition for a topology, as the complement of an open set need not be open (it does however, need to be closed). If you got rid of the "or complement of open set" part, then you've recast the definition of a topology in terms of defining a suitable *characteristic function* on $\mathcal{P}(X)$.

You may be interested in a somewhat different construct. Topologies could alternatively be defined in terms of what sets are required to be *closed* instead of which ones are required to be open. I like to call such an object a *Cotopology* in reference to the natural duality is has with actual Topologies.

Specifically, one can define a Cotopological space $(X,\xi)$ as set $X$ together with a collection of subsets of $X$, $\xi$, such that:

1. $\emptyset$ and $X$ are in $\xi$.
2. The union of any *finite* collection of sets in $\xi$ is in $\xi$.
3. The intersection of *any* collection of sets in $\xi$ is in $\xi$.

The subsets in the cotopology are exactly those sets that are *defined to be closed*. Such a space has a natural topology given the collection $\tau =\{ S|S^c \in \xi\}$ where by $S^c$ I mean the complement of $S$ in $X$. Likewise the cotopology can be derived from the topology by the analogous construction (demonstrating the duality between these constructions).

Comment: cotopology is already taken (see [here](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/duke-mathematical-journal/volume-37/issue-2/Cotopology-for-metrizable-spaces/10.1215/S0012-7094-70-03737-3.short), defined by de Groot, a famous Dutch topologist).

Comment: I became aware of that after posting this (decided to check if that was the case). Guess I will need to think of another name for this construction.

Comment: It's actually quite a common alternative axiomatisation in text books. But it adds nothing new, just a trivial exercise in definitions. One can also use "net convergence" or "neighbourhood spaces" or "closure spaces" etc.